# How to Delete a 000000 file in S3 bucket in AWS using a hive script

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, hive

I've created a working hive script to backup data from dynamodb to a file in S3 bucket in AWS. A code snippet is shown below

```
INSERT OVERWRITE DIRECTORY '${hiveconf:S3Location}' 
SELECT *
FROM DynamoDBDataBackup;
```

When I run the hive script it probably deletes the old file and creates a new file but if there are errors in the backup process I guess it rolls back to the old data because the file is still there when an error has occurred.

Each day we want to make a backup but I need to know if an error has occurred so I want to delete the previous days backup first then create a backup. If it fails then there is no file in the folder which we can automatically detect.

The filename gets automatically named 000000

In my hive script I've tried unsuccesfully:

```
delete FILE '${hiveconf:S3Location}/000000'
```

and

```
delete FILE '${hiveconf:S3Location}/000000.0'
```

Perhaps the filename is wrong. I haven't set any permissions on the file.

I've just tried this but fails at STORED

```
SET dynamodb.endpoint= ${DYNAMODBENDPOINT}; 
SET DynamoDBTableName = "${DYNAMODBTABLE}";
SET S3Location = ${LOCATION};

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DynamoDBDataBackupPreferenceStore;

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DynamoDBDataBackupPreferenceStore(UserGuid STRING,PreferenceKey STRING,DateCreated STRING,DateEmailGenerated STRING,DateLastUpdated STRING,ReceiveEmail STRING,HomePage STRING,EmailFormat STRING,SavedSearchCriteria STRING,SavedSearchLabel STRING),   
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.dynamodb.DynamoDBStorageHandler'
```

LOCATION '${hiveconf:S3Location}',
    TBLPROPERTIES ("dynamodb.table.name" = ${hiveconf:DynamoDBTableName}, "dynamodb.column.mapping" = "UserGuid:UserGuid,PreferenceKey:PreferenceKey,DateCreated:DateCreated,DateEmailGenerated:DateEmailGenerated,DateLastUpdated:DateLastUpdated,ReceiveEmail:ReceiveEmail,HomePage:HomePage,EmailFormat:EmailFormat,SavedSearchCriteria:SavedSearchCriteria,SavedSearchLabel:SavedSearchLabel");

Answer (score 3):

You manage files directly using Hive Table commands

Firstly if you want to use external data controlled outside Hive use the External Command when creating the table

```
set S3Path='s3://Bucket/directory/';

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS S3table
( data STRING
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
       FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
   LOCATION ${hiveconf:S3Path};
```

You can now insert data into this table

```
 INSERT OVERWRITE TABLE S3table
    SELECT data
    FROM DynamoDBtable;
```

This will create text files in S3 inside the directory location
Note depending on the data size and number of reducers there may be multiple text files.
Files names are also random GUID element i.e. 03d3842f-7290-4a75-9c22-5cdb8cdd201b_000000

```
DROP TABLE S3table;
```

Dropping the table just breaks the link to the files

Now if you want to manage the directory you can create a table that will take control of the S3 directory (Note there is no `external` command)

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS S3table
( data STRING
)
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
       FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
   LOCATION ${hiveconf:S3Path};
```

If you now issue a drop table command all files in the folder are delete immediately

```
DROP TABLE S3table;
```

I suggest you create a non external table then drop it and carry on with the rest of your script. If you encounter errors you will have a blank directory after the job finishes

Hope this covers what you need

Comment: I get what you are saying and added the changes to the end of my post above. However because I'm mapping dynamo columns to the table I don't think I can set the location at the same time. At any rate I get this error - mismatched input 'STORED' expecting EOF near ''s3://...Backup''

Comment: I would need to drop the table first then create it. However I can't dreate it in 1 step. From what you say I create a table. But I need to insert data into that table. If that fails then I want to delete it.

Comment: Ok then to drop the table do the following 

set S3Path='s3://Bucket/directory/';

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS S3table ( data STRING ) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LOCATION ${hiveconf:S3Path};

DROP TABLE S3table;

then you can carry as you before creating your table dynamically

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS DynamoDBDataBackupPreferenceStore....

Comment: Its still not clear...1) create external table, 2)drop table (i don't get why to drop a table i've just created?), 3)create table in normal way with mapping (but how do I tell it the location unless i've got the syntax incorrect)

Comment: I think I haven't explained my situation properly...The hive script needs to delete the file or table in S3 and recreate a new table with the same name with new data - you are saying i should create then drop 'S3Table' then create another table. I don't understand how creating and dropping a different table can help.

Comment: Apologies to clarify, delete the file from the directory by linking a new table to the directory  CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS S3table ( data STRING ) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' LOCATION ${hiveconf:S3Path};  Now remove the file by removing the table DROP TABLE S3table; You now have an empty directory and can use your script as before to build a new table linked to s3 and a file will be created when you insert data into this new table